# nodejs throws error with mysql like query via prepared statements

Tags: mysql, node.js

Am retrieving values from database using nodejs.
I implemented mysql like query via prepared statement to ensure that sql injection attack is eliminated. my problem is that **it does not retrieve any result. it just show empty results in the console** please can someone point to me what is wrong with the query

```
exports.autosearch = function (req, res) {
//var search = req.body.searchText;

var search = 'bukatti';
//db.query('SELECT * FROM users WHERE name like ?', ['%' + search + '%'], function (error, results, fields) {


db.query('SELECT * FROM users WHERE name like ?', ['%search%'], function (error, results, fields) {
console.log(results);






});



}
```

Thanks

Comment: You are searching for the string `"search"`, not for the contents of the variable `search`. Actually the line of code that is commented seems the way to go. Also, have you tried to `console.log(error)`? I don't see any error handling in your code.

Comment: Thanks George.  your right. i added the error log and discover that the was type error somewhere. This fix it anyway 
db.query("SELECT * FROM users WHERE name like ?", ['%' + search + '%'], function (error, results, fields) {

Comment: Np :-) You will be able to select your own asnwer as correct in a few days.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have found out my problem. i added the error log and discover that the was type error somewhere. This fix it anyway

```
db.query("SELECT * FROM users WHERE name like ?", ['%' + search + '%'], function (error, results, fields) {
```

Thanks